# Neo4j How do I get this query to use an index?

Tags: database, neo4j

I have this query and it refuses to use an index, idk if it's because the "Expand" stage in the pipeline or what exactly, but I can't get it to use an index in this form, especially in the ORDER BY clause, it still gives me a "Sort" stage in the planner, and I'd like to avoid it.

The index is the createdAt property.

```
PROFILE
MATCH (u:User {user_id: '61c84762da4e457d55656efa'})-[follows:FOLLOWS]->(following:User)-[relatedTo:POSTED|SHARED]->(everything)
WHERE relatedTo.createdAt > datetime("2000-02-12T15:42:10.866+00:00")
RETURN u, relatedTo, everything
ORDER BY relatedTo.createdAt DESC
```

Here is a picture of the planner

[image: Plan 1]

The only way it does what I want it to do, is if I remove everything prior to the last relation, which obviously defies the point of that query but it was just for testing.

```
PROFILE
MATCH (following:User)-[relatedTo:POSTED|SHARED]->(everything)
WHERE relatedTo.createdAt > datetime("2000-02-12T15:42:10.866+00:00")
RETURN relatedTo, everything
ORDER BY relatedTo.createdAt DESC
```

Now it uses the index.

[image: Plan 2]

Any ideas how to do I get it to use an index in both, the query & the sort?

Comment: Can you share the command with which the index is created?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear why you want to use an index?
In your first query an index is used to find the `:User` node and then relationship pointers are followed to find the other nodes of interest. In Neo4j following relationship pointers is always faster than trying to use an index to find nodes (unlike a relational database). Typically, you only want to use an index to find your start nodes in a path, which is what your first query is doing.
If you really want to split the query to start the index search in a different part of the path you could split the query into multiple parts using `WITH`.

Comment: I basically want to use an index on the createdAt property, to sort using that property. Neo4j won't use the index in the ORDER BY clause unless I use it in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cypher [planner hints](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/using/#_hinting_a_relationship_type_scan) to indicate to the planner that you'd like it to use specific index(es) for a `MATCH`. The planner is free to ignore a hint, especially if using it would change the result.

The following is an example of using hints for your `POSTED(createdAt)` and `SHARED(createdAt)` indices. (I also attempted to speed it up a little by ensuring the threshold `datetime` is only calculated once.)

```
PROFILE
WITH datetime("2000-02-12T15:42:10.866+00:00") AS threshold
MATCH (u:User {user_id: '61c84762da4e457d55656efa'})-[:FOLLOWS]->(:User)-[relatedTo:POSTED|SHARED]->(everything)
USING INDEX relatedTo:POSTED(createdAt)
USING INDEX relatedTo:SHARED(createdAt)
WHERE relatedTo.createdAt > threshold
RETURN u, relatedTo, everything
ORDER BY relatedTo.createdAt DESC
```

The following is my resulting profile (I had no actual data). Notice how the planner decided to use both hinted relationship indices, and also the `User(user_id)` node index (which is automatically created for the associated uniqueness constraint).

[image]

As for the sort at the end, I see that your profile shows that sorting did cause any DB hits, so the sorting should have been fairly quick.